# Enlaces profundos Deeplink en Android

Tags: java, php, android

Cómo se puede implementar un sistema de `Deeplink` estilo la app tinder.

Es decir, en la opción compartir con... se añade una url estilo `http://go.tinder.com/md5`

El quien recibe el mensaje en whatsapp, telegram etc... si pulsa sobre el enlace puede pasar dos cosas:

- Si el usuario no tiene la app, le abre la google play con la app.
- Si el usuario tiene la app, se abre, se procesa el enlace y lo sitúa en la pantalla con la información.

Entiendo que el sistema de depplink de android, si la app no está instalada se abre el enlace con el navegador web. Si la tiene instalada delega su petición hacia ella, evitando la apertura en el navegador.

**Cosas que tengo realizadas:**

Enlace de ruta patrón: https://caminsderonda.wordpress.com/2016/08/22/cami-de-ronda-playa-sant-pol-a-playa-sa-conca/

- Enviar mensaje y el enlace con compartir con `Share This` hacia whatsapp, telegram, notas etc...

**Me falta:**

- Procesar el deeplink desde la app si el usuario la tiene instalada.
- Como saber que ruta cargar en la app? supongo que debería añadir algo en la url para tener una referencia númerica indexada en la base de datos de rutas en la app.

Comment: Este enlace a la [documentación](https://developer.android.com/training/app-indexing/deep-linking.html) de Android igual te puede servir

Answer (score 2):

En los métodos "onCreate" o "onStart" de la actividad puedes hacer esto para recuperar la url.

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
Uri data = intent.getData();
```

En data tendrás la url que activó la aplicación y ahí puedes añadir algún id u otro parámetro si es necesario.

Para saber qué actividad tiene que cargar la app puedes dar un vistazo a la [documentación deep link](https://developer.android.com/training/app-indexing/deep-linking.html) explica cómo crear filtros para que una url carge una u otra actividad.